# in sql anywhere, can i get the SQLSTATE full message text

Tags: sqlanywhere

refer to [list of SQLSTATE](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/saerrors/sa-errors-by-sqlstate.html)

In my Procedure codes runtime, I can get the SQLSTATE 5 characters string. But how can I get the full message too?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ERRORMSG function

```
SELECT ERRORMSG( '01W02' );
Using temporary table
```